# How to store the output of a print statement in a for loop as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variables, printing

```
for i in vl:
    if i.startswith("$"):
        print(i.split(" ")[0])
```

I want to store the output of that last print statement as a variable but I don't know how. Trying to save it as a variable within the for loop or after it returns a "doesn't do anything" error.

Comment: output of print statement will always be a None. do you want to store value of i.split(" ")[0] in a variable?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that too but I can't use the variable anywhere outside of that for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable before the loop and then fill it. This way the variable is present even if the if conditions are not executed.e.g.

```
variable = 'Default'   # create variable
for i in vl:
    if i.startswith('$'):
        variable = i.split(' ')[0]  # fill variable if the if conditions execute
print(variable)
```

Comment: I think it worked but it I can't use this variable anywhere. Says it's undefined.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? If you have it inside a method or function the error may occur.

Comment: v = input("Your variable list: ")

vl = v.splitlines()
vl = [n[6:] for n in vl]
for i in vl:
    if i.startswith('$'):
        variable = i.split(' ')[0]
vli = variable.split("""
""")
print(vli)

Comment: I edit my answer. For me it works like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though this thing will still take more iterations before I can get it to return the result I'm looking for. Greatly appreciate it.